# What is our stance on website recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

What is our stance on website recommendation questions?  Are they on-topic or off-topic? Assume that the website recommendation pertains to statistics / machine learning.

Example:

> Is there any web-based demo that returns the k nearest words given a word using GloVes (English)? http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo is great but only has word2vec.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 8):

The example you give certainly seems off topic, but let's assume that the recommendation request would be on topic (which seems to be the intent of this question).  In that case, the thread could fall within the scope of our [references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) tag.  Indeed, we have [a number of requests for website recommendations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[references]%20website%20is%3Aquestion) under that tag.  The [top voted thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/7351/) states,

> I don't want to read a Bayesian textbook just yet. I'd prefer to read from a source (website preferred)...

Looking for a website that, say, provides a tutorial is clearly on topic.  That thread is old and has never been a candidate for closure.  It is highly viewed, highly upvoted, and with several upvoted answers.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't a website be used for something else than a reference while still being on-topic on this Stack Exchange website, e.g. to visualize models or output (example: https://playground.tensorflow.org)?

Comment: It's certainly possible that a question about a website that isn't a reference request could be on topic, but it's hard for me to think of an example right now. The example you show looks plainly off topic; asking for a website that you could use to visualize a model sounds like software recommendation / plainly off topic as well.

Comment: A practical detail is that threads based on websites are more likely to require maintenance. A decade or so on, it is possible that a good book is out of print, but still available in libraries or as a used (second-hand) book, but more likely that a website has disappeared or moved; or that whatever was up-to-date is now sadly neglected. But the principle that website recommendations can be welcome surely stands.